# Db Context Loading Issue entity framework 5

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

In my application ,the Db Context take too much time for loading at the time of initialization.
How can I reduce the loading time at the time of db context initialization.

Comment: Hi... try this link http://morshedanwar.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/getting-performance-benefit-from-dbcontextef-5-in-distributed-architecture/

Comment: Are you sure that it is just creating a new DbContext that takes a lot of time? How much time does it take to create a new DbContext?